# Error al usar transmute: the condition has lenght > 1

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

Estoy intentando cambiar los valores de unas columnas de un `data.frame`.

Tengo los siguientes datos de pruebas:

```
library("tidyverse")

puntuaciones <- c(1.9, 2, 3.5, 4, 5)
satisfaccion <- c(3, 2, 1, 4.2, 5)

df.test <- data.frame(puntuaciones = puntuaciones, satisfaccion = satisfaccion)

View(df.test)

dt.test <- transmute(df.test, punt = cambiarEscala(puntuaciones))
```

Pero devuelve lo siguiente:

> Warning message:
> Problem with `mutate()` column `punt`.
> i `punt = cambiarEscala(puntuaciones)`.
> i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

La función cambiarEscala() es la siguiente:

```
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {
    # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
    if (floor(x) == 1) {
        return((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[1])
    }
    if (floor(x) == 2) {
        return((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[2])
    }
    if (floor(x) == 3) {
        return((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[3])
    }
    if (floor(x) == 4) {
        return((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[4])
    }
    if (floor(x) == 5) {
        return((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[5])
    }
}
```

`v.correccion` es un vector con la correlación que le correspondería en cada caso. La función por sí sola funciona, pero es cuando estoy intentando usarla con una columna cuando falla.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se da porque estas aplicando la función a todo el vector puntuaciones y no a cada elemento, por ende, el R solo se lo aplica a la primera fila y luego se lo repite a toda la data.

puedes hacer:

```
df.test$id = 1:nrow(df.test)

df.test %>% group_by(id) %>%
  transmute(punt = cambiarEscala(puntuaciones))
```

Crear un id, luego agrupar y así te aseguras que la funcion sera aplicado a cada grupo, es decir a cada fila

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Bastián.

Answer (score 2):

Como mencionan @Bastian Andres el problema es que `if` es una función vectorizada y regresa el resultado de la prueba lógica para todo el vector `x`. Puedes usar el `group_by` con una variable `id` para que evalúe cada grupo a la vez o puedes directamente utilizar la vectorización a tu favor.

En este caso la ubicación del factor de corrección corresponde al piso (entero) de `punt`, así que podrías usarlo para encontrar el factor de corrección sin necesidad de los `if`.

Algo así:

```
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {(x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + v.correccion[floor(x)]}
```

No es necesario agrupar o iterar, la vectorización hace todo el trabajo.

Comment: que eficiente, me gusto esta solución

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mpaladino. Realmente las tres soluciones me han solucionado el problema, una lástima que sólo pueda dar una como válida, lo único que cambiar la función no es viable porque la suma no equivale al entero de x, sino que es otro valor diferente, aún así muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

`transmute()` va a reciclar el mismo valor si tu función no está vectorizada. Ya que estás usando `tidyverse` puedes aprovechar para iterar la función que ya creaste. La solución de [@mpaladino](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/47366/mpaladino) me parece la mejor opción, pero si no quieres reescribir la función (quizás la que tú escribiste la entiendes muy bien y la otra no) puedes iterarla con `purrr::map_dbl()`.

```r
dt.test <- transmute(df.test, punt = map_dbl(puntuaciones, cambiarEscala))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Samuel. Realmente las tres soluciones me han solucionado el problema, una lástima que sólo pueda dar una como válida. La tuya es aún más simple, en una sola línea. Os estoy a los tres enormemente agradecido!